# css overflow: auto in FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox, overflow

i have some weird issue.
My page structure looks like this http://codepen.io/usf/pen/enGgE

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://allcrimea.net/photo/big/1337518868.jpg" width="200px">
  </div>
  <blockquote>
    asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdываываывывааыва
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

### scss:

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #FFEFD3;
    min-width: 500px;
    .img  {
        float: left;
    }

    blockquote {
        overflow: auto;
    }
}
```

The problem is in FF this example has horizontal scroll, cus of blockquote has width less on 200px. I thought `overflow: auto` must "repair" this, but FF didnt do that.

I cant set `margin-left: 200px`, cus picture size can be different :(
`float:left` to blockquote help only when the text dont take all of blocks width

How can i get the same result in the chrome and ff?

Answer (score 0):

Not much details, but would `display:inline-block;` work for your situation ?

[Updated example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvAFx)

Comment: I tried this, but http://codepen.io/usf/pen/vopzC when i have a lot of text it doesnt work for me :(

Comment: Does your text needs to wrap around the image if the paragraph is taller than the image ? I know we're said to stay away from tables for presentation, but sometimes it is ok.. [See example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DGiom)

Comment: unfortunately i cant use the tables there..i think there is some easy solution, but cant get it

Answer (score 0):

If the width does not have to fixed then you could just add

```
blockquote { width: auto; float: left }
```

which should do the trick?

Comment: Well you could add a max if you want to restrict inside of a container like so max-width: 600px; if you want the text to start wrapping at 600px for example.